# Not able to read ids of other Views in a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

On click I am retrieving id of the view and making it's visibility `GONE`
**using**

```
public void click(View view) {
 Context context = getApplicationContext();
 final int position = view.getId();
 Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 if (button_number == 1) {
  View btn = view.findViewById(position);
  if (btn != null) {
   btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
 }
}
```

This is just for testing purpose I want to accomplish different action on other views but am only able to retrieve one `TextView` only   

[image]
**Test1** is a `TextView` i am only able to retrive on each list item(*as you can see on click it's not visible*)
[image]

**xml** is here

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#5894CA"
    android:clickable="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:text="Bank of baroda details...."
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="click"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"

        android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
        android:background="@drawable/share"
        android:onClick="click"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton3"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:onClick="click"/>
        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gnome_edit_delete"
        android:onClick="click"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="148dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/details"
android:onClick="click"
>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:text="Sample"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/td"
    android:onClick="click"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i click rest of the image button or layout  or other textview i am getting a null object from the id, i think there is a mistake in my xml due to which i am not able to retrieve other views, 
any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: XML you have posted is different. Please check.

Comment: @FebiMathew no i have posted the right xml i am using it in a custom list